# Fastest Search in ArrayList<String>(a sorted)

Tags: java, search

I am interested in the fastest search in sorted `ArrayList` of `String`.
What is a fast way?

I am using method `contain`, but i think, there is a better way.

What about 2 threads?
One from the front and second from behind.

List sorted contains elements of the same length.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
.
.
```

What what is your opinion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Java provides [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)).